# How can we program this in UNIX shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a flat file with N columns.

The Nth column contains word 'abc' several time at different rows.

How can I replace this word 'abc' with 'def'.

The output file should contain the same data till the 'N-1' columns, only in the Nth column the multiple occurences of the word 'abc' should be changed to 'def'.

Please advise on how to acheive this.

Regards,
Srihari

Comment: Are the columns fixed-width, or variable width with a delimiter?  If there is a delimiter, can it also occur within the fields (presumably quoted or escaped somehow)?

Comment: Hi Chris, The delimiter is unique ex ':'

Comment: The columns are variable width. The delimiter doesnot occur in the data. Thank you.

Comment: Post some sample data if it doesn't work

Comment: Hi Say where are we referring to the Nth column in this command; suppose my Nth column is 9 where will it fit in in this command?

Comment: Will the command by default look into the Nth column i.e final column

Comment: Yes, changing `$NF` will always change the last column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32286/discussion-between-srihari-and-js)

Comment: Hi JS please help me modifying this command as per below 2 requirements

Comment: requirement 1:  In the 5th column of the flat file , blind update with "def" should be done ,irrespective of the value present 
there( value can be anything ex: abc,xyx,foo,den etc ).remaining other column values should remain unchanged
-------------------------------------------------------------------
requirement 2:  In the 5th column of the flat file,if the value is present as "abc" it should be replaced with "def",remaining 
                other column values should remain unchanged.

Comment: Both requirements are on 5th column?

Comment: yes JS both are on 5th column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{$NF=($NF~/abc/)?"def":$NF}1' your_file
```

Comment: Hi JS thank you very much for the answer , can you please explain me the above command, thank you once again for your time

Comment: You're welcome. `NF` represents number of fields. `$NF` will represent the last column. So if our last column is like `abc` we change it to `def`. If it isn't we leave it as is. `1` tells `awk` to print the lines with or without the changes.